# export or download gridview with custom table schema C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

[My Gridview Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmPQj.png)  I have question ..So i have Grid where the data are binding from SQL..And i will export/download file to .XML files..its success but the header table XML files are not same with "Schema" on Grid..ex= i have field
'Actual Duty On Time In' on grid but on exporting file .XML field header name changes to 'Actual_Duty_On_Time_In'...[My Table .XML Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myyCN.png)

The question is.. can i customize the "Schema" in C#...so the .XM file are same with grid schema?

This is my code

```
GetData();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dtxml = ((DataView)GVHostDtl.DataSource).Table;
ds.Tables.Add(dtxml);
ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/" + xmlFileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I always use this method and works just fine :

```
private void ExportGridToXML()  
    {  

        SaveFileDialog SaveXMLFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();  
        SaveXMLFileDialog.Filter = "Xml files (*.xml)|*.xml";  
        SaveXMLFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;  
        SaveXMLFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;  
        SaveXMLFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";  
        SaveXMLFileDialog.FileName = "myXml";  
        SaveXMLFileDialog.Title = "XML Export";  
        if (SaveXMLFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  
        {  

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
            DataTable dtxml = (DataTable)ViewState["Data"];  
            ds.Tables.Add(dtxml);  
            ds.WriteXml(File.OpenWrite(SaveXMLFileDialog.FileName));  

        }  
        XMLFileThread.Abort();  

    }
```

Comment: I got eror message "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."

Comment: it works with my code before but the "Schema" was Different

Comment: try to add [STAThread] before your main function which call the method.

Comment: also you can check this link for other possible issues : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2411f889-8e30-4a6d-9e28-8a46e66c0fdb/current-thread-must-be-set-to-single-thread-apartment-sta-mode-before-ole?forum=clr

Comment: Im done to add (Thread XMLFileThread;)...But still got same message error...But tq for ur answer